# Explanation of a simple example of how an interaction net computes?

Tags: programming-languages, interaction-nets

I have briefly looked through the links at the bottom of [this page](https://wiki.xxiivv.com/site/interaction_nets.html):

- Interaction Nets
- Interaction Combinators
- Implementation of a low-level language for interaction nets, Shinya Sato
- Inpla, Interaction Nets as Programming Language
- Towards a Programming Language for Interaction Nets, Ian Mackie
- An Implementation Model for Interaction Nets
- Interaction Nets Playground
- Bologna Optimal Higher-Order Machine

That covers most of the stuff on the web about interaction nets it seems.

But without being a mathematician, I am struggling to get beyond the basic terminology, which doesn't resonate intuitively upon my initial readings.

- agent
- connection
- port
- net
- rule

They describe that agents are nets which connect through their principle ports, etc.. But what does this mean in terms of practical computation? I don't follow the visual diagrams of the nets either, so they aren't of much use to me yet.

Could you provide an example of some simple function taken from an imperative programming language (such as `add`, `multiply`, or iterating through some list or something), and explain how it would work from an interaction net perspective? What is doing what, how do the 5 names map to the parts of such a simple example program? I am having a hard time understanding the terminology, and applying it to a practical problem of representing some imperative function using the parallelizable interaction net paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Interaction nets are a form of graph rewriting.  Nets are graphs made up of some finite number of labelled nodes with connections between them.  If two nodes have the same label then they have the same number of ports, that is places where they can connect to other nodes.  Exactly one of these ports is noted as a "principal port" and these are important in determining which rewrite rules to follow.

The rewrite rules define how computation is done on a net by defining how to replace nodes.

For example, taking your "add" request, let's consider adding unary numbers: where we use Z to represent zero and Sx to represent the successor of a natural number x.  Counting 0,1,2 is therefore Z,SZ,SSZ.

We need to represent Z.  All we have is nodes, so lets define a node for Z.  All this does is have a label Z on it and a port so it can be connected to other nodes:
[image: s]

We put a little arrow on the wire coming out of it to identify this as a principal port connection.  (It has to be a principal port because, as noted above, each node has exactly one principal port).

Then we need a node to represent the successor of a number.  This is a node labelled S which has one connection to the number it is a successor of and another connection available to the rest of the net. The connection that is not the principal port we call an auxiliary port:

[image]

This way we can represent any natural number either by the Z node alone or the number *n* where *n>0* by *n* S nodes connected together with a Z node at the bottom.

[image]

To implement "add" we need some interaction rules.
Interaction rules take a pair of nodes, connected via their principal ports, and define what to replace them with.
If nodes are not connected via their principal ports they cannot be rewritten in this way.  This is why principal ports are important.

Each pair of nodes has exactly one interaction rule, so if a pair can be rewritten there is no choice of how to rewrite it.

The only other restriction is that we must have the same number of auxiliary ports on both sides of the rewrite rule.

So how do we write rules for "add" given the unary number format?

We can consider two cases:

1. We are adding zero to a number, 0+y, which returns y
   or
2. We are adding a successor number to a number, Sx+y, which can be rewritten as S(x+y).

So we can use rule 2 recursively until we get down to zero.
e.g. 2+1 is SSZ+SZ -> S(SZ+SZ) -> S(S(Z+SZ) -> S(S(SZ) = SSSZ, or 3.

The first rule can be drawn like this where we have a new node "add" which has two auxiliary ports and one principal port:

[image]

Where we read out the answer at the "result".  Remember y will be a Z node or some stack of S nodes with a Z at the bottom.

And the second rule like this:

[image]

The example of 1+2 --> 3 can be drawn as:

[image]

(note that the middle diagram should have an arrow from the top S as this is a principal port).

Then we can go off and define multiply, sorting algorithms etc etc by creating nodes to represent the data and the functions, and a set of rules for the computation we want.

It is a remarkable feature of this system that it is Turing complete.

Hopefully that provides some help to you.